# Node js loop in res.render

Tags: json, node.js, express

Hey Everyone i have a router that basically pulls in a JSON file and outputs various instances of the array. When i console.log the title in my for loop it loops through and outputs and each instance is outputted, works great. When i put my res.render inside of the for loop and pass it the same variable being looped in the console.log it will only output the first instance. Does anyone know why this is? and is there a way to loop through the res.render to output all instances in the JSON same as the console.log.

Thank you for your time,

```
router.get('/fuelTypeFilter', function(req, res, next) {

        var url = "Example.JSON"

        request({
            url: url,
            json: true
            }, function (error, response, obj) {

             if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                // console.log(obj) // Print the json response
                for(key in obj.categories){
                    var img = obj.categories[key];
                    var title = obj.categories[key].product_category_title;

                    console.log(title);
                    // console.log(obj.categories[key]);
                } 
                res.render('fuelTypeFilter', { title: 'Fuel Type', item: title });
            } //end of if 

        }); // end of request  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What `res.render` does is basically serve up a plain HTML file with some template inserted, so with data like the object you pass into the render call. Therefore, `res.render` acts like a `return` statement, as in when your code reaches that mark, it signals to the router that we need to render this page (present in the browser to user), therefore we must be done with our router handling logic.

As to whether it's possible to 'loop through' render calls, the answer is no since that would be implying to just, even if succeeded, present however many pages you want instantaneously one after the other, so in that perspective, you wouldn't really want to keep making render calls as your view in the browser would effectively keep refreshing moment after moment.

One way to do this with `render` is just package your array-like data into the object that you pass into `res.render` and then, assuming you are using some sort of templating engine, do something analogous to a 'for loop' there, looping and printing the elements as, say HTML divs.

Hope this is a bit helpful.